# Adobe Sign server side REST API

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, echosign

I need to implement server side Adobe Sign REST API interactions that require OAuth authorization. Server side does not allow to do it. How this question can be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

When you say "server-side does not allow to do it", do you mean on the Adobe Sign end or within your application?

If it is on your side, then there is an alternative connection option which is an integration key, which is a static key. You can request that to be enabled in your account from Support by clicking the (?) in the top-right corner when you are logged into Adobe Sign.

If you are saying that Adobe Sign is not allowing the configuration of OAUTH, make sure that you have the right level of subscription. You need to have Adobe Sign Enterprise in order to have access to APIs.